# MySQL Cannot Parse Zero Hour (e.g. "0:30am")

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

For some reason, MySQL can't seem to parse "zero" hour times in the format:

0:30am

Tried padding and forcibly replacing the zero hour, but all 5 hour formats ("%l", "%H", "%h", "%I", "%k") doesn't seem to work.

The following query demonstrates the issue.

```
SELECT
HOUR('0:30am'),
REPLACE(' 0:30am', ' 0:', ' 00:'),
LPAD('0:30am', 7, 0),
STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(' 0:30am', ' 0:', ' 00:'), '%h:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE(LPAD('0:30am', 7, 0), '%h:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(HOUR('0:30am'), ':30am'), '%h:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE(LPAD('0:30am', 7, 0), '%l:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE(LPAD('1:30am', 7, 0), '%l:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE(LPAD('1:30pm', 7, 0), '%l:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE('0:30am', '%l:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE('0:30am', '%H:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE('0:30am', '%h:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE('0:30am', '%I:%i%p'),
STR_TO_DATE('0:30am', '%k:%i%p');
```

Comment: One reason why you should never store dates in text format

Comment: Indeed... Sucks to manipulate data you didn't store. :-)

Comment: `00:30 = 12:30 AM` [link](https://mathlearnit.com/what-time-is-00-30#:~:text=Convert%2000%3A30%20to%20AM%2FPM%20format&text=The%20time%2000%3A30%20may,AM%20in%2012%2Dhour%20time.). Maybe you should update `update your_table set col ='12:30am' where col ='0:30am'`